Ubuntu not displaying in VMware full-screen until logged in
I have Ubuntu installed on VMware, but the screen doesn't go full screen until I log in (even though VMware is in full-screen mode). [Screenshot attached below]
After logging in, the screen fills correctly. Even if I return to the login page later due to inactivity or shutdown, it displays correctly. What could be causing this issue? Thanks!

